# why do we use the same name for the variable as the typename for a namedtuple , in python?

Tags: python, class, tuples

In python documentation an instance of the namedtuple is created by :

```
Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
p = Point(11, y=22)
```

Is it necessary to use the variable name same as the typename of the namedtuple ? and is there any benefit of doing this ?

Comment: No, it isn't necessary. But Most classes are assigned to a variable with the same `__name__`, e.g. `class Foo: pass` creates a class with a `__name__ == 'Foo'` and assigns it to a variable `Foo`. You *could* if you wanted to `Bar = Foo; del Foo` and now there's only a variable named `Bar` which refers to the class

Comment: thank you ,then why people use it this way? is there any benefit ? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Because it's consistent with everything else? Why would you want to do it differently? You understand `namedtuple` is a class factory that creates a class, not an instance, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, if you used different names, the following would be unnecessarily confusing:

```
> from collections import namedtuple
> Foo = namedtuple('Bar', ['x', 'y'])
> a = Foo(1, 2)
> print(a)
Bar(x=1, y=2)
```

Comment: It'll also cause problems with pickling and unpickling instances of the named tuple, it needs the assigned name to match the definition name.

Comment: i think i have a lot to study ,i dont know about pickling and unpickling

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you may prefer the newer typed version that does not on its face appear duplicative.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple

```py
class Employee(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    id: int = 3

employee = Employee('Guido')
assert employee.id == 3
```

Comment: Although, this has the horribly unintuitive result that `isinstance(employee, NamedTuple)` will return `False`, since `NamedTuple` isn't a true type, rather, it merely uses the metaclass machinery to essentially call the regular `namedtuple` class factory under the hood. In python, "practicality beats purity", I suppose, but this one really bothers me.

Comment: Of course, but for that matter, `isinstance(regular_named_tuple, namedtuple)` would fail. The type is `tuple`. With this example you get the benefit of also having a type `Employee`, and type annotations.

Comment: Yes, but I think since `namedtuple` is a class factory, and is clearly used like a factory, one wouldn't expect that `isinstance` should return true, and would expect that to raise an error. But I agree, being able to type-annotate the namedtuple class is good.